# Customizing Spring Boot project structure

Tags: spring-boot

I am a bit intrigued by Spring boot project structure.

When I create a spring boot project using Eclipse (with Spring tools plugin) and spring initializr (in eclipse Spring->Spring Starter Project), there is no folder src/main/webapp/WEB-INF created. Now is that (src/main/webapp/WEB-INF) to be created manually? If not how to create that directory using spring Spring Starter Project ? If Spring Starter Project is not answer how to create it using some kind of wizard. I am using eclipse with "spring tools" plugin (sts+spring-ide)

I have searched in the web and I am yet to find my answer. Please guide.

In short I am looking for answers to what (and how) are the customization options for project structure in a spring boot project.

Comment: And why you think you'll need that folder?

Comment: Spring Boot by default does not use WEB-INF folder, neither web.xml. Configurations are now with annotations and config files like `.properties` are in `src/main/resources`. For more information, read this: https://ralphavalon.wordpress.com/2017/07/04/10040/